# Change background color of entire row in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic table which data's are coming from an API. I'm generating the table and inserting rows using JavaScript.

Everything is working properly but the problem is in styling.

My table row colors are stripped (just like we use bootstrap table-striped class) and cells are not same in every row.

Some has 3, some has 6, some 4 etc. Where cells are less they are showing some blank space.

Is there any way i can color the entire row. Here is an example. Here is an example of my code:

```css
.table-striped th {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #bfff00 !important;
  color: #191919;
}

.table-striped td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-striped>tr:nth-child(n+1)>td {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

.table-striped>tr:nth-child(n+2)>td {
  background-color: #e8e7e6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Header 6</th>
      <th>Header 7</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6</td>
      <td>Cell 7</td>
      <td>Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfg5hxz7/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you have there is NOT a properly defined `table`. In a `table` all rows have the same number of cells.

Comment: i have a scenario where cells number are not equal.

Comment: Doesn't matter...they really **should be**. If they are not, you're doing probably something wrong.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484768/can-html-table-have-variable-number-of-cells-on-rows

Comment: @Paulie_D i'm showing data from google sheet. where not every cell have any value. I checked. Nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: Every cell doesn't have to have a *value* ...but the cell has to **exist** (even if empty) to be considered part of the "row".

Comment: Pseudo classes won't work if trying to update rows in table, try to refresh whole table instead.

Answer (score 2):

The table row is only as wide as the number of cells.

Add a final cell when you don't have a full row and use `colspan` as appropriate.

```css
.table-striped th {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #bfff00 !important;
  color: #191919;
}

.table-striped td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e8e7e6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Header 6</th>
      <th>Header 7</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6</td>
      <td>Cell 7</td>
      <td>Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Basic_styling) that :

> Any styles applied to the `<tr>` element will affect the cells within
>   the row unless overridden by styles applied to those cells.

Pay particular attention to the fact it styles the cells, not the row itself

**EDIT**

We know from your question and comments that you are using javascript to generate the table. We can't infer much on how you are doing this, but if you are generating the table row by row you should be able to see if you have generated the amount of cell for that row equal to the amount of `th` cells. If not, add a cell with the difference as a `colspan`. If you can't do this you can do it *after* the table is created.

This is a rough way of doing it

```js
function addColspan(table) {
  //Assume number of th are our max cells per row
  var maxCells = table.querySelectorAll("th").length;
  
  //Get all rows but the first
  var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(n+2)");
  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    //Get how many cells we have
    var cellCount = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td").length;
    //If we don't have enough cells
    if(cellCount < maxCells) {
      //Add one with the appropriate colspan
      rows[i].innerHTML += "<td colspan='" + (maxCells - cellCount) + "'></td>";
    }
  }
}

//Run after table is generated
addColspan(document.querySelector(".table-striped"));
```

```css
.table-striped th {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #bfff00 !important;
  color: #191919;
}

.table-striped td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e8e7e6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Header 6</th>
      <th>Header 7</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6</td>
      <td>Cell 7</td>
      <td>Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But those cells are dynamic. I just can't use colspan. I used this code as for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `even` and `odd` properties in css.
Check this out

```css
.table-striped th {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #bfff00 !important;
  color: #191919;
}

.table-striped td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #e8e7e6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Header 6</th>
      <th>Header 7</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6</td>
      <td>Cell 7</td>
      <td>Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

Updated answer after the comment. You need to have alteast empty  in order to highlight the complete rows.

```css
.table-striped th {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #bfff00 !important;
  color: #191919;
}

.table-striped td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #e8e7e6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Header 6</th>
      <th>Header 7</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6</td>
      <td>Cell 7</td>
      <td>Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: My requirement is, i need to change the color of entire row. check your cells, where it has empty cell its not showing the color

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am creating those fields based on api response, For single row if the api has 3 data i am creating 3 cells. So I can't determine how many cells will be for the next row.