# Does each <tr> need an equal amount of <td>s?

Tags: html

Let's say I have

```
<tr>
   <td>Hi</td>
   <td>Hi</td>
   <td>Hi</td>
   <td>Hi</td>
   <td>Hi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Bye</td>
   <td>Bye</td>
</tr>
```

without any colspan attributes. Both Chrome and Firefox will correctly render the two cells of the second row and then leave "3 TRs of empty space".

My question is:
**Is this actually syntactically allowed in HTML or something the browsers are merely "auto-fixing"?**

Comment: Think `td` as cells rather than columns: After all, a `td` can span [multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows); so non-equal number of them are perfectly fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can HTML table have variable number of cells on rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484768/can-html-table-have-variable-number-of-cells-on-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an HTML table, you must have an equal number of headings and cells.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Browsers always try to fix bad HTML when showing data to the user.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This would show correctly to the user, but it is invalid HTML code.

To make sure your HTML is completely correct, try XHTML.

What is XHTML?

- XHTML stands for EXtensible HyperText Markup Language
- XHTML is almost identical to HTML
- XHTML is stricter than HTML
- XHTML is HTML defined as an XML application
- XHTML is supported by all major browsers

Here is a bad example of XHTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is bad HTML</title>

<body>
  <h1>Bad HTML
  <p>This is a paragraph
</body>
```

Here is a good version of XHTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Title of document</title>
</head>

<body>
  some content
</body>

</html>
```

You can validate your code at an [XHTML Validator like this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html).

For more information of tables and how they work, check out the [W3 page of tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html).

[W3Schools Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)
[W3Schools XHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is not valid html. If you run this through an html validator, e.g.

https://validator.w3.org/

You will get this error:

> A table row was 2 columns wide, which is less than the column count
>   established by the first row (5).

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bye</td>
    <td>Bye</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

All modern browsers will render this correctly, but if you want to have valid html, use `colspan` to balance out the rows:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bye</td>
    <td colspan="4">Bye</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not an error though but a "warning"... if possible, I'd want to leave it as-is (it's auto-generated content that might end for example with 5 tds in the first but 1 in the 2nd row), but if it's actually incorrect html, I'll fix it. Is there a definite word somewhere in the spec?