# html table is not building properly | cannot merge cells

Tags: html, html-table

I cannot really understand what I'm doing wrong, trying to merge cells.
I've started building complex table with great proportions, at the end, unfortunately, when I opened it in browser it displayed everything in 1 row. So I took a smaller example in order to understand where and why I was doing something wrong.

Everything worked fine, until I decided to remove `<td colspan="2">5</td>`  in the 3rd row and change `<td colspan="2">5</td>`into  `<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">5</td>` in the 2nd one.
After that the table has just somehow transformed for no reason.
Link to before-after images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlOBm.jpg

```html
<table border="1">
  <!-- 1 -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td colspan="2">5</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">5</td>

  </tr>
  <!-- 3 -->
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <!-- 4 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- 5 -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>

    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- 6 -->
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- 7 -->
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td colspan="4">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can HTML table have variable number of cells on rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484768/can-html-table-have-variable-number-of-cells-on-rows)

Comment: No, it's not. I tried to accomplish the task the same way as it was successfully performed in comments of your question. I wanted to remove some <td> in order to make space for 2х2 cell. For some reason it didn't work out.

Comment: Assuming you want 7 total rows to show -- row 3 is completely blank so it collapses down into nothing.  Having items in row 2 using rowspan="2" would work if there was something else in row 3, but without anything specifically there, row 3 doesn't really exist (is not display-able).

Comment: thanks, I figured it out. It turns out, the <table> is such an inflexible thing =/